# Homeomorphism of $I / \sim$ with $S^{1}$.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I have the following exercise:

> Show that if $I = [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\sim$ is the equivalence relation $x \sim x´$ if and only if $\{x, x´\}$ = $\{0,1\}$ or $x = x´$, then $I / \sim$ is homeomorphic to $S^{ 1}$.

**My attempt:**

My first idea was to use the parametrization of the unit circle, that is, $f (x) = (\cos (2 \pi x), \sin (2 \pi x))$ and in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3368533/identifying-this-quotient-topology) publication they also "construct" it.

The problem I have is that we know that a homeomorphism is a function between two spaces, bijective, continuous and with continuous inverse. From the problem clearly the $f$ that I provide is bijective, but how do I know that the inverse is continuous, or how do I obtain said inverse?

Another way to attack the problem would also be to see $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the complex plane and use the function $f (x) = e^{2i \pi x}$, but it seems to me that in this case we would have to make the composition of $f$ with another function than give us a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ with the complex plane.

I do not have much experience in homeomorphisms, for that reason the doubts that I present previously have arisen, in advance, thank you.

Note: $S^{1}=\{x\in \mathbb{R^{2}} : \|x\|=1\}$.

Comment: There's the theorem that a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space must be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Do you know any theorems about quotient maps?

Comment: @Angina Seng, Yes, I know that result, the problem is that they ask me to do this without the use of theorems, I am just seeing an introduction to quotient spaces. Thanks also

Comment: @Matematleta, no, I have not seen any theorem about quotient spaces yet, what they ask us is to do it with the definition basically.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the map $f:I/\sim \rightarrow S^1$ given by

$$f(\theta) = (\cos(2\pi\theta), \sin(2\pi\theta)) \in \mathbb{R}^2.$$

It is continuous because each component function is continuous (i.e. cosine and sine are continuous functions). Consider the function $g:S^1 \rightarrow I / \sim$ given by

$$
g(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\arccos(x)}{2\pi}, & y \geq 0, \\
\frac{-\arccos(x)}{2\pi} \mod 1, & y < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Here, we are thinking of $\arccos$ as a continuous bijective map $[-1, 1] \rightarrow [0, \pi]$.

One can check that $g$ is continuous and that it is the inverse of $f$. Therefore, $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Note: By "mod 1" I mean that $-1.05 \equiv -0.05 \equiv 0.95 \mod 1$.